# Go: Format string according to keywords

Tags: go

In Go (golang) what would be the best way to format a string like this:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from foo where col1 > 1000 and col2 < 2000
```

To this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM foo 
WHERE col1 > 1000 
    AND col2 < 2000
```

Would it be best to split it up, then if it's a keyword insert a "\n" in front of it. And if it contains AND etc. also add a tab or spaces in front of it.

But what if the string was like this:

```
if (1 > 0)
begin
if (2 > 1)
begin
select * from foo
end
end
```

Then the formatting get's a little more complicated, since you would need additional tabs for the inner query after the begin. And also the 2nd begin would also need to be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this truly right you need a full-fledged SQL parser. [This one](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/vitess/go/vt/sqlparser) could work, but for what I see the output is not really what you are looking for. So you'd need to tweak it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that should give me some good pointers. The formatting with tabs etc. was pretty easy. For the keywords groups I just used map[string]struct{}.